# Jmeter dynamic URL property with variable not substituted

Tags: dynamic, jmeter

I have a simple Jmeter test where I have a property to set the URL. The PATH in the Jmeter test is set to the following.

```
${__P(GET_URL,)}
```

This works well for all URLs that I have been working with, except for the ones where I need to pass a variable in the URL component.

For example, it works for `http://server:port/getemployeelist` when I run the test with `-JGET_URL=/getemployeelist`

Then I created a CSV config element to populate the variable `EMP_ID`.

Then if I run the test with `-JGET_URL=/getemployee/${EMP_ID}`, the `EMP_ID` variable is not getting substituted. Jmeter test gives me an error as follows:

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index xx: https://://getemployee/${EMP_ID}

Appreciate any help/pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work this way, JMeter doesn't know anything about `${EMP_ID}` at the time it is being started, you need to append this `${EMP_ID}` to [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler "Path" in the runtime

1. Start JMeter as:

   ```
   jmeter -JGET_URL=/getemployee/
   ```
2. Use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read the `EMP_ID` from the CSV File

   [image: JMeter CSV EMP ID]
3. In the HTTP Request sampler use construction like `/${__P(GET_URL,)}/${EMP_ID}` to combine JMeter Property specified via `-J` command line argument and JMeter Variable originating from the CSV file.

   [image: JMeter properties and variables concatenation]

If anything goes wrong first of all check *jmeter.log* file - it normally contains enough troubleshooting information. If there is nothing suspicious - use [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) to inspect requests and response details, variables and properties names and values, etc.

Comment: Thank you. What I was trying to do is, to use a single jmx to test a bunch of my REST APIs by invoking jmeter -JGET_URL=url1, -JGET_URL=url2 and so on. 

_url1_ needs a ${EMP_ID} as you have shown in the example above, but _url2_ cannot have ${EMP_ID} in the URL. Since the CSV data config for EMP_ID is part of the jmx, every URL that I pass in -JGET_URL would get this EMP_ID and would not work. Hence the trouble.

Comment: Use [__evalVar()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__evalVar) function instead like `/${__P(GET_URL,)}/${__evalVar(EMP_ID)}`. If your EMP_ID variable will not be initialised - the value will be blank, if the variable will have the value - you will see the value in the path. See [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) JMeter User Manual chapter and [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series to get familiarized with JMeter Functions.

Comment: @DmitriT - this solution doesn't work for me - it's just blank all the time

Answer (score 0):

Had asked this question a while back. Thought of posting the solution which I eventually ended up implementing. In the solution, I created a template jmx with a substitution variable for the HttpSampler.path and then replace the path at runtime. Following are the key points from the scripting done.

This turned out to be a simpler solution that worked for all kinds of API call patterns.

1. Created a template jmx (jmeter_test_template) with the following line.

`<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">#PATH#</stringProp>`

This jmx has CSV config element to populate variable "EMP_ID". To create this file, just create a new test with any URL and then save it as a template and replace the URL with substitution variable #PATH#.

2. Created a wrapper script like run_any_api.sh with usage,

`sh run_any_api.sh URL=http://server:port/myapp/employees/${EMP_ID}`

3. In the wrapper script, this URL is replaced in place of the token.

`sed "s/#PATH#/$URL" jmeter_test_template.jmx > jmeter_test_template.current_test.jmx`

`jmeter -t jmeter_test_template.current_test.jmx`

4. Last but not the least, please remember to cleanup the temporary jmx,

`rm jmeter_test_template.current_test.jmx`